# What techniques can I use to block human generated spam posts?

Tags: spam, spam-prevention

I'm having trouble blocking paid posters trying to post links to products unrelated to "fashion" on my site. I've made my links `nofollow` but they're still being posted. What techniques can I use to combat this?

Currently, I delete the posts and am building a way for community members to flag and remove spam posts. I'm also blocking IP addresses but this doesn't seem scalable since new people just crop up.

Comment: Hi, just wondering if my answer helped :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you not just require that any post with a hyper-link must be approved before going live? This is what I do on my site. You can catch most of the spam and let the occasional legitimate post through with a genuine link.

Comment: Thanks for your response. My site is Pinterest-like, in that it aggregates products for fashion posted by users. Problem comes when people post things like a tin of tea to the site. If I stopped links for moderation, it would very much limit the user experience, and I get 150/day and growing so that would become very hard to police. Would love any other ideas!

Comment: How about black/white listing domains then? As the lists grow you should have to do less and less work. Admittedly, it's not a very accurate method as a domain could contain things that you do and don't want on any given post/page. Sounds to me like you could do with getting some moderators on board! Unfortunately this can be a bit of a pain to get right.